# SVG image not displaying correctly inside a div in android phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova, svg

when I load svg image inside a div with certain width and height in android phonegap, the image displays full screen covering all the other div rather than in its designated div and cannot proceed further. The svg is loaded dynamically, the example snippet for now is

```
<div style="width:400px;height:400px" >
   <object width="100%" height="100%" data="test.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

The same code works for IOS but it is giving problems in android. Also, sometimes it loads perfectly for the first time but when the image is changed since it is loaded dynamically, it again displays full screen.  I am testing in Android ICS. Has anybody else faced same problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, update your phonegap version. The svg rendering was fine in latest version of cordova: 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the android browser. I am working on it too, can't find any legitimate solution.